# Rails Postgres query on hstore to avoid SQL injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord, sql-injection, hstore

I have a class `User` that has an `hstore` attribute `:preferences`. If I want to find all Users where the `startpage` key in their preferences is `nil` I can do:

```
User.where("preferences @> 'startpage=>NULL'")
```

How can I structure that query so it avoids SQL query injection?

Tried:

```
User.where("preferences @> :key '=>NULL'", key: 'startpage')
User.where("preferences @> :key IS 'NULL'", key: 'startpage')
User.where("preferences @> :key IS NULL", key: 'startpage')
User.where("preferences @> ? IS NULL", 'startpage')
```

Without luck.  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The `@>` operator expects hstores on both sides. When you say:

```
some_hstore @> 'startpage=>NULL'
```

PostgreSQL will implicitly add the `::hstore` cast as if you had said:

```
some_hstore @> 'startpage=>NULL'::hstore
```

But there are other ways to create an hstore. From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html#HSTORE-FUNC-TABLE):

> Function: `hstore(text, text)`
>   Return Type: `hstore`
>   Description: make single-item hstore

So you can switch to the more explicit `hstore(text, text)` function and let ActiveRecord do its normal thing with placeholders and strings:

```
User.where("preferences @> hstore(:key, null)", :key => 'start page')
```